# How to use Pusher-JS within VS Code's Angular workflow?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, pusher

I've got this following short piece of JavaScript code from a company that offers market data through Pusher and it works well as it is.

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var placeholder = document.getElementById('trades_placeholder'),
        pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
        tradesChannel = pusher.subscribe('live_trades');

    tradesChannel.bind('trade', function (data) {
        placeholder.innerHTML = "Price: " + data.price + "<br>Timestamp: " + data.timestamp;
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to make it work within the Vs Code's Angular-TypeScript workflow but I'm getting these following errors:

[image]

I've installed pusher-js through npm.

Here's the image with all the code I've made in my Angular project files, I've marked all the relevant Pusher-JS changes in yellow:

[image]

it's obvious I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is. Below I have attached both the JavaScript and Angular (only relevant not the whole project) files in the zip so you can have a look, unfortunately I couldn't provide the pushers key number but it doesn't matter as I only need to know how to properly set the project up.

**ATTACHEMENT:** [JavaScript file and Angular TypeScript files ZIP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLqSOHobU3k43sv5wfYfufEJguGp9Dc8/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
import { Pusher } from 'pusher-js';
```

needs to be this:

```
import * as Pusher from 'pusher-js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think We need to tell TypeScript that Pusher exists as a global variable, otherwise we’ll get errors from the compiler. Add the line below to the top of `app.component.ts:`

```
declare var Pusher: any;
```